# Ignoring segue resource in R.Swift

Tags: ios, swift, build, cocoapods, uistoryboardsegue

How to ignore segue generators in R.swift cocoa pod file "R.generated"

Answer (score 0):

With [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift), you can configure which generators should be run.

For example adding the flag: `—-generators image,string` will only generate those two structs. By manually excluding the `segue` generator from the list, those won’t be generated.

For more details, see the [documentation](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Ignoring.md#only-run-specific-generators-exclude-rsomething).